# Html form textboxes storing values in modals?

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have used modal in my html form and I am using angular $scope varible to bind textboxes using ng-model so if I am opening modal first and enter some value and just close the modal and reopen it then the values which was previously entered remains as it is.I want to make it blank on whatever times modal will open . I tried by putting autocomplete = "off" in input tag but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the input values use the following on modal close i.e

```
$('#my-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(".modal-body input").val("");//this will reset all the input values
});
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: great answer @AKSHAY JAIN